# Saving entity and Upload file

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I have an ASP.NET Web API app and I'm doing CRUD on it using breezejs. It is working great, but now I need to save an image. The user will inform a user name and some other data and select a image. What I do not get yet is how I should process this. Should I save the entity with breeze and after that upload the image and update the entity with the filePath? Should I save it all together (I think that this is impossible). So my 2 questions are: Can someone explain to me the commom way of doing this (save first, upload after?) and if there is something already baked in web api/breeze to help me?